# How many characters are in given array but spaces

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, continue

I am trying to find out how many characters are in the given array except blanks
but it's not working, k supposed to count  blanks and substract them from i[characters + blanks] but it doesn't.

```
int i= 0;
int n= 0;
int k= 0;
char c[256] = {};
fgets(c ,256, stdin);

while(c[i] != '\0' ){
     if(c[i] == ' '){
             i++;
             k++;
             continue;}
i++;}


printf("%d",i-k);
```

Comment: Other than the fact that the code requires the compiler to implement an extension of accepting an empty pair of braces as a valid initializer, I see no inherent problem in the code presented.  To render an answer with any confidence, we need to review a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As a wild guess, however, try either adding a newline to your printf format (`"%d\n"`) or flushing the standard output after the printf (`fflush(stdout);`) or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observation, here

```
fgets(c ,256, stdin);
```

`fgets()` stores `\n` at the end of buffer if read. From the manual page of `fgets()`

> If a `newline` is read, it is **stored into the  buffer**.
>          A  terminating  null  byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in
>          the buffer

Remove the trailing `\n` first and then iterate over it. For e.g

```
fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
c[strcspn(c, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the trailing \n */
```

Also use of `continue` is not required here i.e you can achieve the task without using it. For e.g

```
int main(void) {
        int i= 0;
        int k= 0;
        char c[256] = ""; /* fill whole array with 0 */
        fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
        c[strcspn(c, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the trailing \n */
        while(c[i] != '\0' ){ /* or just c[i] */
                if(c[i] == ' ') {
                        k++; /* when cond is true, increment cout */
                }
                i++; /* keep it outside i.e spaces or not spaces 
                        this should increment  */
        }
        printf("spaces [%d] without spaces [%d]\n",k,i-k);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: You don't have to remove trailing \n. Just calculate i-k-1 instead of i-k.